# Why does JPA modifying query require @Transactional annotation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Given the code below, why is it that when I call `PersonService.updateAccountMembership` from a controller I need to have the `@Transactional` annotation on the `@Modifying` query (`AccountRepo.updateMembership`)?  Isn't having the `@Transactional` annotation on the service call that calls the modifying query sufficient (`AccountService.updateMembership`)?

The code below would break if I remove the `@Transactional` annotation on the modifying query with the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class PersonService{
    @Autowired
    PersonRepo personRepo;

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    public Person updateAccountMembership(Person person, int membership){
         person = this.save(person);
         accountService.updateMembership(person, membership);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person save(Person person){
        return personRepo.save(person);
    }
}
```

Account Service:

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
     @Autowired
     AccountRepo accountRepo;

     @Transactional
     public void updateMembership(Person person, int membership){
          accountRepo.updateMembership(person, membership);
     }
}
```

Account Repo:

```
public class AccountRepo extends JpaRepository<Account,Integer> {
     @Transactional //WHY IS THIS REQUIRED????????
     @Modifying
     @Query("update .........")
     void updateMembership(@Param("person") Person person, @Param("memb") int membership);
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be needed however make sure that transactions for the `AccountService` are actually applied. Also the call to `this.save` isn't transactional as it never passes through the proxy that applies the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Sure

You have two kinds of queries in sql. Read-Queries and Write-Queries.

A database can have multiple clients. What if two clients update the gender of a person at the same time? The last one wins!

This is an example using two methods: `void buy()` and `void pay()`.

1. Client A read next empty invoice number 0000001
2. Client B read next empty invoice number 0000001
3. Client A change invoice0000001-payer to Max
4. Client A store invoice 0000001
5. Client B change invoice0000001-payer to Tom
6. Client B store invoice 0000001 <<--- crash! Already in use!

**Problem: Max buyed it, but Tom payed it.**

If you use transactions you can bind step 5 with step 6. If Step 6 failed, Step 5 is rolled back.

Your database across-the-board requires transations. You can not modify data without.

Comment: I think the questioner understands Transactions but is asking why the configured transaction does not propogate from the Service layer to the Repository layer in this case.

Comment: @AlanHay The exception he describs talks to me: he is not using it via the Service layer.